# Filter bigquery table based on Id and dates from another table

Tags: mysql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am new to big query and I am trying to get some data using two big query table. The first table has id and purchase dates and the second date has all the user activity with a date column for the day of the activity.

What I am trying to do is for all the ID from the first table, get all the activity for all those id from the second table such that activity date is between the date from the purchase table and 30 week back from the date of the purchase table.

```
WITH
  purchasers AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `table1`),

  activity AS(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `table2`
  WHERE
    date BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(purchasers.four_week_back,INTERVAL 30 week))
    AND ((purchasers.four_week_back)) )

SELECT
  *
FROM
  purchasers
JOIN
  activity
USING
  (id)
```

```
Table 1- 

Id      product_type_id     created_at      four_week_back
594157      72               2018-09-27     2018-03-01
10532522    72               2018-09-27     2018-03-01
535061      72               2018-09-27     2018-03-01
10740216    72               2018-09-27     2018-03-01
6093925     72               2018-09-27     2018-03-01
1712485     72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
3381129     72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
4290069     72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
647413      72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
10482204    72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
6585925     72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
1409073     72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
10749573    72               2018-09-28     2018-03-02
```

```
Table 2- 
id  date        varA    var2 
594157      2018-02-19  5637    TRUE
594157      2018-02-04  43160   FALSE
594157      2018-01-17  43160   TRUE
10740216    2018-02-06  43160   FALSE
10740216    2018-02-19  43160   TRUE
10740216    2018-02-09  43161   FALSE
10740216    2017-12-27  43161   TRUE
4290069     2018-02-18  43161   FALSE
4290069     2018-01-05  43161   TRUE
4290069     2018-02-07  43161   FALSE
4290069     2018-02-18  43161   TRUE
4290069     2018-02-19  43161   FALSE
4290069     2018-01-27  43162   TRUE
```

However I have been unable to do so. The desired output is that for all the id from the table 1, get the activities from table between the date range (table1.date and table1.date, 30 week interval).

Comment: See if you have more criteria for the join at least more than id. You should also read up on joins.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The desired output is that for all the id from the table 1, get the activities from table between the date range (table1.date and table1.date, 30 week interval)

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING (id) 
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 30 WEEK) AND created_at
```

Note: you can use `SELECT *` in above assuming that there are no other ambiguous columns rather than `id`

Below is example for you to test with

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 594157 id, 72 product_type_id, DATE '2018-09-27' created_at, DATE '2018-03-01' four_week_back UNION ALL
  SELECT 10532522, 72, '2018-09-27', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 535061, 72, '2018-09-27', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10740216, 72, '2018-09-27', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6093925, 72, '2018-09-27', '2018-03-01' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1712485, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3381129, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 647413, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10482204, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6585925, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1409073, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' UNION ALL
  SELECT 10749573, 72, '2018-09-28', '2018-03-02' 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 594157 id, DATE '2018-03-19' day, 5637 varA, TRUE var2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 594157, '2018-03-04', 43160, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 594157, '2018-01-17', 43160, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 10740216, '2018-03-06', 43160, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 10740216, '2018-03-19', 43160, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 10740216, '2018-02-09', 43161, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 10740216, '2017-12-27', 43161, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-02-18', 43161, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-01-05', 43161, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-02-07', 43161, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-02-18', 43161, TRUE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-02-19', 43161, FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 4290069, '2018-01-27', 43162, TRUE 
)
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.table1` t1
LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2` t2
USING (id) 
WHERE day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 30 WEEK) AND created_at
```

with result

```
Row id          product_type_id created_at  four_week_back  day         varA    var2     
1   594157      72              2018-09-27  2018-03-01      2018-03-19  5637    true     
2   594157      72              2018-09-27  2018-03-01      2018-03-04  43160   false    
3   10740216    72              2018-09-27  2018-03-01      2018-03-06  43160   false    
4   10740216    72              2018-09-27  2018-03-01      2018-03-19  43160   true
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, is there something missing at the end of the query after `AND created_at`

Comment: not really! and btw, i assumed `created_at` field is of data type `DATE` - why you asked?

Comment: created_at is of type DATE and sorry I misunderstood it. Silly question!!

Comment: no problem. added example for you to test. note: slightly modified your initial data (in table2) otherwise there was no qualifying rows in activity

Answer (score 0):

Please see below query:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH purchasers AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' id, DATE '2019-09-01' four_week_back UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' id, DATE '2019-09-01' four_week_back UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ccc' id, DATE '2019-09-01' four_week_back
), activity AS (
  SELECT 'aaa' id, DATE '2019-09-01' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa' id, DATE '2019-08-15' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa' id, DATE '2019-08-01' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'aaa' id, DATE '2018-07-01' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' id, DATE '2019-10-01' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' id, DATE '2019-08-15' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' id, DATE '2019-08-01' date UNION ALL
  SELECT 'bbb' id, DATE '2018-07-01' date 
)
SELECT a.*
FROM purchasers p, activity a
WHERE p.id = a.id
  AND a.date BETWEEN (DATE_SUB(p.four_week_back,INTERVAL 30 week))
    AND ((p.four_week_back))
```

Output:

```
+-----+------------+
| id  |    date    |
+-----+------------+
| aaa | 2019-09-01 |
| aaa | 2019-08-15 |
| aaa | 2019-08-01 |
| bbb | 2019-08-15 |
| bbb | 2019-08-01 |
+-----+------------+
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the response. I should have updated an example for the tables which I have done now. I hope the query you shared would work on these two tables. Would I have to write the ids again and again. I am working on table size of 27 million

Comment: Given the size of your data, it will be a good idea to start with some sampled data instead of spending money on debugging your query.